# How to slice by string value on a pandas multiindex level

Tags: python, pandas

I have a multiindex with the following levels...

```
df_sorted.index.names

FrozenList(['Date', 'Store', 'Department', 'Category', 'Subcategory', 'UPC EAN', 'Description'])
```

Within the 'Subcategory' level the labels are:

```
df_sorted.index.get_level_values(level='Subcategory').unique()

Index(['Ales', 'Lagers', 'Liqour', 'Liquor', 'Malts', 'Red', 'Rose', 'Stouts',
       'White'],
      dtype='object', name='Subcategory')
```

I'm attempting to return a slice of this index by string value, i.e. return all values between 'Malts' and 'Stouts'.

It's easy to do this by position.

```
df_sorted.index.get_level_values(level='Subcategory').unique()[4:8]
Index(['Ales', 'Lagers', 'Liqour', 'Liquor', 'Malts', 'Red', 'Rose', 'Stouts',
       'White'],
      dtype='object', name='Subcategory')
```

But I would like to do something like this:

```
df_sorted_index.get_level_values(level='Subcategory).unique()['Malts':'Stouts']
```

This line clearly doesn't work as pandas/python is expecting integer values for the slice rather than strings.

I've been trying a number of approaches including, for example:

```
idx = pd.IndexSlice
df_sorted.loc[idx[:,:,:,:,'Malts':'Stouts',:]]
```

However, this throws an Indexing error 'Too many indexers'.

Any ideas of the best way to try and slice a sub-level in a multiindex by name rather than position?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you need [`get_locs`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.get_locs.html#pandas.MultiIndex.get_locs) to get the index positions:

```
idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([list('ABCDEF'),list('abcdef')])
df = pd.DataFrame(range(6), index=idx)
#     0
#A a  0
#B b  1
#C c  2
#D d  3
#E e  4
#F f  5

df.iloc[df.index.get_locs([slice(None), slice('c','e')])]
#C c  2
#D d  3
#E e  4
```